# AMP for article pages only?

Tags: html, progressive-web-apps, amp-html

My boss wants to add AMP to our new site, we already have a responsive website and have added PWA.

The site is a blog/news site, so does AMP need to be on each article page only? Or do we need to have a AMP for every page?

Answer (score 1):

that's a good questions. The answers depends on multiple things:

- is amp possible for the whole page?
- what do you wan't to achieve?

It is no problem to mix amp-pages with non-amp pages.
If you use amp your are very limited in css and own javascript.

An mean idea is to deliver only what the user realy need.
Use safe cdn, webfonts and some special amp-elements.

All pages witch uses amp are cached by google, your users can load the content extremly fast.

If you use amp for your articles you can great cool things:
It's possible to present your news in some special formats.

https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/news-publishing/news_article/?format=websites

more informations you can find also here: https://amp.dev/documentation/templates/

Comment: thank you @larabee, the site is quite heavy on graphics, so I thought of just the article pages and if the user clicks on about us it wold redirect to the resonsive side of the site. I guess we also want the articles to appear on Googles new page (swipe left on Android devices) and carousel on the search results.